# google recaptcha v2 is not responsive in some mobiles

Tags: css, responsive, recaptcha

I'm using google recaptchav2, but on some mobiles verify button is not reachable.

[image: google recaptcha v2]

I'm sure it's because of `left:161.68px` on a div without any id or class.

[image]

How can I make it responsive?

Comment: Same issue here. Please! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you verified on real mobile device ?

Comment: @ShammiSingh, yes, I tried on my phone, and the same problem exists.

Comment: If this is coming from an external service then your best bet would be to contact them and tell them that they have a problem with mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help you. Add class using jquery.(Can you please share the link of this page ?)

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("iframe").parents("div").addClass('g-active');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I use a way like this.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[2].parentElement.parentElement.setAttribute('id', 'g-main');

Answer (score 1):

While not the most ideal solution, it is possible to style the recaptcha wrapper using the `z-index` as a unique identifier in the CSS selector, and override the position and layout to fit on a mobile device;

```
/* Reposition RecaptchaV2 on mobile using z-index as selector */

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  div[style*='z-index: 2000000000;'] {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 1rem !important;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 12px
  }

  /* Hide the bubble arrow */
  .g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Note: Consider replacing any use of this specific `z-index` throughout your codebase with a different value.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont given an id to that element then you can give a condition in js file like if width of the div element is greater than vw(viewport width)then set width according to the mobile width.otherwise give that div a height and width.

Comment: Unfortunately, that div was created by ReCaptcha and I can give it id or class.

Comment: ok use a id and give  width to 100% and bottom:0 and padding-bottom: as your wish . this 3 styles you have to use to show that div element

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and resolved it by adding CSS like below.
I believe you just need left property to fix the overflow.

```css
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    /* selector for overflow div */
    div[style*='box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 2px 2px 3px;'] {
      left: 0 !important;
    }
}
```